# Access Queries Over Date Range

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an access query that will run to calculate the total activity in a location at a specified time. Is there a way to run this over a range of dates and return the results using SQL or should I write a form to run the query various with dates from code?

To make matters slightly more complicated, the query is also dealing with radioactive decay, correcting each item to its current activity at the time requested - although this can probably be ignored for testing.

Finally, on a slightly unrelated note, items and arrive and leave a location at any time, but it is unfeasible to have data points for each second of every day, so I am using three hour intervals as a compromise - as radioactive decay follows an equation, anyone have a better way of doing this (so that data is plotted as soon as an item arrives, otherwise the decay from the arrival time and plotted interval can effect my result a lot) or is this the best I am likely to manage?

Current SQL for single date:

```
SELECT FORMAT(SUM(Items.Activity*(Exp(-(0.693*(dDate-Items.MeasuredOn)/Nuclides.HalfLife)))), '#,##0.00') AS CurrentActivity
FROM Nuclides INNER JOIN ((Locations INNER JOIN (Items INNER JOIN ItemLocations ON Items.ItemID = ItemLocations.ItemID) ON Locations.LocationID = ItemLocations.LocationID) INNER JOIN LocationLimits ON Locations.LocationID = LocationLimits.LocationID) ON (Nuclides.Nuclide = Items.Nuclide) AND (Nuclides.Nuclide = LocationLimits.Nuclide)
WHERE (((ItemLocations.LocationID)=lLocationID) AND ((ItemLocations.RecieptDate)<dDate) AND ((ItemLocations.DisposalDate)>dDate Or (ItemLocations.DisposalDate) Is Null));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could no figure out how to solve in the way I initially imagined, so solved as follows instead:

User inputs a date range for the time period they want to view data for.

One query to return single list of all dates when an event happened (date item added, date item removed)

Using set time intervals (now one hour) activity calculated at the time until an event time is reached. At event time activity is calculated for half a second before the event occurred and the time of the event itself. We then continue with our hour intervals until the next event.

After final event keep calculating at the interval until the end time is reached.

This works quickly enough to not be a problem for the user, and the graph is as smooth as it needs to be. FYI activity is also calculated half a second before events to give a vertical slope on the line, otherwise it will be slanted from the previous point (potentially an hour or more of time).